# find index position of wrong spelled letters in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Find the indexof wrongly spelled words in an array

The code That I have tried:

```
function check(arr) {
  var check = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(orchard);
  for(var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){

          return arr[i].indexof(check);

  }


}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited. please check

Comment: Thanks, will the orchard always contain at least 3 elements? (otherwise, impossible to determine which is correct without a preset dictionary or something, right?)

Comment: what you're trying to do with `onChard[i].indexOf(check)`, your check value will always be true or false as it is return value of `regex test`

Comment: Hang on I share code that  I want to test against..

Comment: @CertainPerformance I shared please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the correct spelling, then use `findIndex` to get the incorrect index.

```js
function findWrongWayFruit(orchard) {
  let correct = orchard[0] == orchard[1] ? orchard[0] : (orchard[0] == orchard[2] ? orchard[0] : orchard[2]);
  return orchard.findIndex(e => e != correct);
}

console.log(findWrongWayFruit(['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'elppa', 'apple']));
```

Comment: can u please help me how to return the number of full turns.1 full turn === 360 degrees